# Программное изменение содержимого ячеек таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Ячейка таблицы с содержимым имеет следующий вид:

```
'<td id="CValue">' + '<span style="display:none" class="fullvalue">' + elem.ControlValue + '</span>' + reduceControlValue(elem.ControlValue) + '</td>'
```

`elem.ControlValue` - это текст с html-тегами, который необходимо отображать в яейке. Так как этот текст очень большой, я его обрезаю функцией `reduceControlValue`, и вывожу его в ячейке.

```
function reduceControlValue(aValue) {
    if (aValue.length > 200) {
        return aValue.substr(0, 200) + "...";
    } else {
        return aValue;
    }
}
```

В каждой строке есть кнопка `edit`, при нажатии на которую ячейка меняет свой вид, в ней появляется `textarea`, в которой отображается весь текст `elem.ControlValue`, не обрезанный.

```
function edtClick(button) {
    var par = $(button).parent().parent(); //tr
    var cvalue = par.children("td#CValue");  
    var Ftext = par.children("td#CValue").children("span.fullvalue").text();
    cvalue.html("<textarea id='txtCvalue'>"+ Ftext +"</textarea>");
}
```

Кроме кнопки `edit` есть кнопка `cancel`, при нажатии на которую ячейка должна приобретать первоначальный вид - то есть `textarea` со всем текстом заменяется обратно на весь текст, который не отображается, и на показанную обрезанную часть:

```
function Cancel(button) {
    var par = $(button).parent().parent(); //tr
    var cvalue = par.children("td#CValue");

    var cvalueNew = cvalue.children("textarea#txtCvalue").val();
    var cvalueShort = reduceControlValue(cvalueNew);
    cvalue.html('<span style="display:none" class="fullvalue">' + cvalueNew + '</span><code>' + cvalueShort + '</code>');
};
```

Проблема в том, что в данном случае, в ячейку записывается только часть `<span style="display:none" class="fullvalue">' + cvalueNew + '</span>`, которая не отображается, а обрезанная часть вообще исчезает.

А если отображать только обрезанную часть в тегах `<code>`, то эти теги не срабатывают и html-теги в тексте преобразовывают текст.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...
    cvalue.html('<span style="display:none" class="fullvalue">' + cvalueNew + '</span><code>' + cvalueShort + '</code>');
    ...
```

Создайте массив шаблон для вашего текста на вставку:

```
    var templ=['<span style="display:none" class="fullvalue">','','</span><code>','','</code>'];
    templ[1]='текст который хочу получить';
    templ[3]='типа еще чего-то';
    document.getElementById('pole').innerHTML=templ.join('');
```

Теперь можно отображать как угодно и удобно.

Тем самым упростите свою задачу разложив на элементы текст обработки
отделив его от обертки html

Думаю мысль понятна?